# Hide tumblr video play button

Tags: css, tumblr

I'm trying to hide the play button of a video posted and hosted on tumblr. When I try `.vjs-big-pause-button-icon {display: none;}` this does not seem to change anything.

Comment: did u try `display:none !important;`

Comment: Yes I did. Has no impact, too. I think the problem is because the button element is in the iframe and the iframe uses a different css file (hosted by tumblr), but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's possible the styles are being written via js, so they would overwrite any local css styles. Do you have a link to the blog, or can you add some code or an example. There will be a js solution, but css would be better/lighter.

Comment: The player is rendered inside an `iframe` which you have zero control over.

Comment: videos are iframes so you can't manipulate them. you could alternatively use `{VideoThumbnailURL}` instead of the videos on the home page but it depends on what the aim of hiding the play button is.

Comment: thank you all for the answers. thats what I thought, too. I just don't like the look of the play button, in my case it's useless. I can hide each of them with the developer tools of chrome, so I thought there must be a way to do this initially.